# count number of Objects in View and Display in Some delay (Animation)

Tags: ios, swift, animation

Actually i want to Show animation base on view Like Present Animation but in background i m going to Push.

Now scenario is like this when i Present view it will show in delay, each and every view (subview) like label, if table then tableViewCell

i just present View in Some delay but not able to show the subview in delay.

i have tried this:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "presentview") as! presentview

let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.8
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
self.navigationController!.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

Comment: i think you should change this value transition.type = kCATransitionPush to kCATransitionFromBottom

Comment: it work perfect when i write Push. My question is while display View subview one should display in some delay